# finite axiomatizability of first order theories?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms

If we consider a single schema as a single axiom, so ZFC for example would be *finitely axiomatizable* after this kind of counting axioms.

By schema its meant a syntactical expression (string of symbols) that contains among its symbols *free* meta-theoretic variable symbols that range over a decidable set of formulas of the language of the theory in such a manner that each substitution of all those metatheoretic variables in the expression by instances (formulas) from what they range over would result in a sentence of the language of the theory. For example the separation schema of Zermelo written as: $$\forall A \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in A \land \phi) \text { is an axiom }$$; Where $\phi$ is a metatheoretic variable that ranges over all formulas of the language in which $A$ doesn't occur free.

This is considered as a single axiom. While the separation schema written as: $$for \ n=1,2,3,...\\ \forall p_1,.., \forall p_n \forall A \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in A \land \phi)$$, that is not a single schema, it is an infinite collection of schemas, so it is not considered as a single axiom.

> Now is it the case that every effectively generated first order theory (with finitely many primitives) is finitely axiomatizable in this sense?

Comment: You have to define "schema."

Comment: Correct! I've added that, see my last edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n\mapsto\phi_n$ be a recursive enumeration of the provable formulas in the given theory, and define $\phi_n'$ to be $\phi_n\wedge\dots\wedge\phi_n$ where $\phi_n$ is repeated $n+1$ times. Given a formula you can check if it's equal to some $\phi_n'$ by seeing if it's equal to some formula repeated $n+1$ times, and then using the fact that $n\mapsto\phi_n$ is computable to calculate $\phi_n'$ and check if it's your formula. Thus the $\phi_n'$s form a decidable set of formulas, and hence a single axiom schema. This construction is also used in the proof of [Craig's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig%27s_theorem).

Comment: You said the $\phi'$s form a single schema! Do you mean a single schema in the sense defined in the question? or just as a decidable set of formulas.

Comment: @Zuhair I was thinking of the schema '$\phi \text{ is an axiom}$', where $\phi$ is a metatheoretic variable that ranges over the $\phi'_n$.